# How can I install xdebug PHP extension in PHP 7.1.14, which is installed on osx high sierra?

Tags: php, macos, docker

Here is php installed version detail on mac:

```
 php -v PHP 7.1.14 (cli) (built: Feb  2 2018 08:41:46) ( NTS ) Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by Derick Rethans
```

Getting error on mac about installed version issue:

> ```
> pecl/xdebug requires PHP (version >= 7.0.0), installed version is 5.6.28
> No valid packages found
> install failed
> ```

Answer (score 1):

copy your `phpinfo()` output, either the command line or the page source of of the output. and paste it in the textarea [here](https://xdebug.org/wizard.php) . you will get custom installation instructions.

Answer (score 0):

```
RUN apt update \
&& apt-get install -y apt-utils locales software-properties-common \
&& locale-gen en_US.UTF-8 \
&& update-locale LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LANG=en_US.UTF-8

RUN LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php \
&& apt update \
&& apt install -y curl git unzip ntp imagemagick \
    php7.1-fpm php7.1-cli php7.1-fpm php7.1-dev php7.1-gd \
    php7.1-curl php7.1-mbstring php7.1-soap php7.1-xml php7.1-readline \
    php7.1-zip php7.1-intl php7.1-pgsql php-imagick php-xdebug \
&& mkdir /run/php \
&& phpdismod -s cli xdebug

RUN sed -i "s/error_reporting = .*/error_reporting = E_ALL/" /etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini \
&& sed -i "s/display_errors = .*/display_errors = On/" /etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini \
&& sed -i "s/memory_limit = .*/memory_limit = 512M/" /etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini \
&& sed -i "s/;date.timezone.*/date.timezone = UTC/" /etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini \
&& sed -i "s/error_reporting = .*/error_reporting = E_ALL/" /etc/php/7.1/fpm/php.ini \
&& sed -i "s/display_errors = .*/display_errors = On/" /etc/php/7.1/fpm/php.ini \
&& sed -i "s/;cgi.fix_pathinfo=1/cgi.fix_pathinfo=0/" /etc/php/7.1/fpm/php.ini \
&& sed -i "s/memory_limit = .*/memory_limit = 512M/" /etc/php/7.1/fpm/php.ini \
&& sed -i "s/upload_max_filesize = .*/upload_max_filesize = 100M/" /etc/php/7.1/fpm/php.ini \
&& sed -i "s/post_max_size = .*/post_max_size = 100M/" /etc/php/7.1/fpm/php.ini \
&& sed -i "s/;date.timezone.*/date.timezone = UTC/" /etc/php/7.1/fpm/php.ini \
&& sed -i "s/;daemonize = yes/daemonize = no/" /etc/php/7.1/fpm/php-fpm.conf \
&& sed -i "s/listen = .*/listen = 0.0.0.0:9000/" /etc/php/7.1/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
```

Comment: still getting this error after executing above command
 pecl/xdebug requires PHP (version >= 7.0.0), installed version is 5.6.28
No valid packages found
install failed

Comment: @KhanMuhammad Can you please add the steps involed in installation including commands in your question.

Comment: i am running docker up then that faces issues with this return 
pecl/xdebug requires PHP (version >= 7.0.0), installed version is 5.6.28
No valid packages found
install failed
ERROR: Service 'worker' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c pecl install intl &&     pecl install redis-2.2.8 &&     pecl install xdebug' returned a non-zero code: 1

Comment: @KhanMuhammad Please refer my updated answer. Put those commands in dockerfile and run the docker-compose up. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For PHP 5.6.28 you need an older xdebug version.

You need to do: `pecl install xdebug-2.5.5`